# python machine learning classification iris dataset

Tags: python

when I am doing the train the model on training dataset ia m getting below error.can anyone pls help

train the model on training dataset

```
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(x_train,y_train)
logreg =LogisticRegression (solver='lbfgs', max_iter=9000)
```

Which produces:

```
/Users/aswanthmanne/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_logistic.py:763: ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.

Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
  n_iter_i = _check_optimize_result(
```

Comment: you mentioned using the iris dataset, can you include the full code on how you derive x_train and y_train so that your error can be reproduced?

Answer (score 1):

Although the question lacks information here are a few tips to make it work:

1. The data is not sufficient and since the data set is known to us so the is a problem in separation which should be as follow:

```py
from sklearn.selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.iloc[:, :4], iris.target)
```

2. The targets are not standardized which the previous code would do the work for this problem too.
3. There is also matters of solver which I don't think that it could be the reason but it is worth talking about. The following is the document for **solver** of sklearn's logistic regression:

> solver{‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘liblinear’, ‘sag’, ‘saga’},
> default=’lbfgs’ Algorithm to use in the optimization problem.
>
> For small datasets, ‘liblinear’ is a good choice, whereas ‘sag’ and
> ‘saga’ are faster for large ones.
>
> For multiclass problems, only ‘newton-cg’, ‘sag’, ‘saga’ and ‘lbfgs’
> handle multinomial loss; ‘liblinear’ is limited to one-versus-rest
> schemes.
>
> ‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘sag’ and ‘saga’ handle L2 or no penalty
>
> ‘liblinear’ and ‘saga’ also handle L1 penalty
>
> ‘saga’ also supports ‘elasticnet’ penalty
>
> ‘liblinear’ does not support setting penalty='none'
>
> Note that ‘sag’ and ‘saga’ fast convergence is only guaranteed on
> features with approximately the same scale. You can preprocess the
> data with a scaler from sklearn.preprocessing.